# ios 9 - tableview cell jumps when scrolling down/up when calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, ios9

Dear fellow programmers,

I've recently updated to Xcode 7 and Swift 2 and now, whenever I'm scrolling down or up , the screen jumps a little bit (nothing too crazy) but it makes it the navigation laggy.
It happens whenever I'm displaying a new cell on the screen when **cellForRowAtIndexPath** is called.

In **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, for each Cell I'm actually setting a bunch of imageView using HanekeSwift, Labels and Buttons (using switch, case, if, etc...).

The weird part is that whenever I comment most of those settings in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, the jumpy part is gone.

I've tried commenting each part but I haven't managed to detect what is responsible for the jump part. Or I was wondering if it could be related to  the fact that there's a lot of treatment.

Each Cell's height is different and I'm using autolayout to detect the height for each Cell.
timelineTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
timelineTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600

I've also tried to implement estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method and calculate manually the height of each Cell but without success.

Anyone has an idea why I'm experiencing the jumpy part and why when I comment everything out, the jump is gone?

**UPDATE 1 :**
while playing with Time Profiler (commenting out some functions in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method), I realize that when the running time of cellForRowAtIndexPath is lower than 80-90ms, I don't see the jumpy part. Also the higher the running time is, the more I feel the jumps

Comment: Use the time profiler in instruments, when running on a device, to find the slow lines. But this is a _lot_ to be doing in a cell preparation method! You're defeating the point of autolayout by switching based on device sizes as well :)

Comment: Do you think that could be related to the fact that this is a lot of cell preparation?  Do I have a choice though? I have to set all of those for each Cell.

Comment: Not all of them need to be done every time. But use instruments to find your slow code, don't guess.

Comment: Here's the result, the two process that takes the longest in my loadItem function : http://imgur.com/JvPDFWw

Comment: If you are using dynamically sized cells (height) it is important that you implement heightForRowAtIndexPath or estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I've tried implementing estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath but it doens't work. And when i'm commenting out most of the treatment in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, the cell are still dynamically sized (height) and I'm not facing any jumps. Somehow, I'm not sure it's related to the height of the cell being dynamic.

Comment: @jrturton : playing around with Time Profiler (commenting out some treatement) I realize that the jumpy part start when cellForRowAtIndexPath's running time is above >80-90ms and the jump increases as the running time is higher.

Comment: Well yes, that's expected :) You get 16ms for the whole run loop to achieve 60fps scrolling

Comment: Even if I try to minimize the calls, I don't that I can get under 90ms though. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your instruments trace, creating and setting button images is taking nearly all the time. That looks like this part:

```
// Approve Button && Disapprove Button
    if selfie.user_vote_status == 1 {
        self.approveButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "approve_select_button.png"), forState: .Normal)
        self.disapproveButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "reject_button.png"), forState: .Normal)
    } else if selfie.user_vote_status == 2 {
        self.approveButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "approve_button.png"), forState: .Normal)
        self.disapproveButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "reject_select_button.png"), forState: .Normal)
    } else {
        self.approveButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "approve_button.png"), forState: .Normal)
        self.disapproveButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "reject_button.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }
```

You can test by commenting out just this part of code first.

To fix this, you need to do two things. First, look at the entire method and try to work out which things you are repeating every time. Those things need to be moved into an initialiser or to be set in the storyboard rather than be hit every time you run.

Second, there is no need to keep creating and assigning these images. The approve button has one of two images, the disapprove button has one of two images. You can set one image for the *selected* state and one for the *normal* state (once, in the storyboard or initialiser) and then just set the selected state of the button based on the vote status.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help!
Could you expand a bit about moving into an initialiser? Like putting all the code that are the same for each Cell into awakeFromNib method?

Comment: Yes, or set it in the nib or storyboard itself.

Comment: Based on your advices, I've somehow managed to reduce everything from 400ms to 120ms for cellForRowAtIndexPath, however, cant seem to get under 90ms. Any other suggestions? I'm kinda surprised though that some simple treatment would cause this as I'm not doing anything crazy, simply setting up images and label :(